# Syncing IntelliJ settings with team

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to figure out how I can use IntelliJ to share settings with team.  I set up a Git repo and was able to do the initial `Sync with Settings Repository -> override remote`.  But I'm not sure how it's supposed to work after that. I have it set to Auto Sync but I can't see any other commits where settings are changed.  I'm also not sure how I can set it up so that not everyone can push changes.  that would defeat the purpose.  We want to use a controlled set of shared changes.  Of course, people can make changes locally, but those shouldn't be pushed.

I also don't see a VCS command on the main menu as the doc keep mentioning. They say there should be a VCS->Sync command, but that doesn't exist.

Does anyone have a good setup for this?

Comment: Have you followed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository ? Readonly repos are also described in docs.

Comment: Yes, I have followed it.  But I still don't see how the automatic syncing works.  And readonly repos leave a lot to be desired.  It doesn't explain how you can control the content on the reasonably repos because it's readonly for everybody.  T

Comment: I'm hoping to get some more practical advice from people who have actually implemented this